# what is the difference between these two way of declare a list in TCL?

Tags: list, tcl

I have a question regarding to the following lines:

```
set list1 "1 2 3 4 5 6" ##line 1
set list2 {1 2 3 4 5 6} ##line 2
```

are these two lines both declare a list?
what is the difference between them?

Comment: For those specific values (`1`–`6`) those are exactly equivalent; they produce _identical_ bytecode.

Comment: Could you please finally consider reading [the tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) to which I keep pointing you while commenting half of your questions?  Really, you're asking about the basics which are well explained there.

Comment: it is a good tutorial, thank you!

Comment: does this mean I can not ask question in the future?

Comment: of course you can ask a question in the future, but it really is in your own interest to understand how grouping works in TCL ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific example, there is no difference.

Neither really declare a list, as you cannot really declare a list in Tcl. But both set your variables to a valid list representation.

The difference only is visible if your items are special to the parser in any way, when "" allows replacements, while {} keeps the content unreplaced.

A third alternative woulde be:

```
 set list3 [list 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```